# How do I show the other sentiment scores from text classification?

Tags: python, text-classification, bert-language-model

I am doing sentiment analysis, and I was wondering how to **show the other sentiment scores** from classifying my sentence: "Tesla's stock just increased by 20%."

I have three sentiments: **positive**, **negative** and **neutral**.

This is my code, which contains the sentence I want to classify:

```
pip install happytransformer
from happytransformer import HappyTextClassification 
happy_tc = HappyTextClassification("BERT", "ProsusAI/finbert", num_labels=3)

result = happy_tc.classify_text("Tesla's stock just increased by 20%")
```

This is the result code and output:

```
print(result)

TextClassificationResult(label='positive', score=0.929110586643219)
```

This is the sentiment score, which only shows the score for positive:

```
print(result.label)
print(result.score)

positive
0.92
```

Now, how do I make it so that it shows the sentiment scores for negative and neutral as well as the positive?

Something that looks like this:

```
positive
0.92

negative
0.05

neutral
0.03
```

Thanks.

Comment: I looked into the source code, and `HappyTextClassification` basically calls the Hugginface transformers for classification. They also unfortunately return only the label with the highest confidence(https://github.com/huggingface/transformers). If you really want to have all scores, then you could maybe build your own sentiment classification model (for example with pytorch) and load in the transformer to do the work. From there you can get all scores.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the helpful information. Is there a guide to build my own sentiment model? Thanks.

Comment: Posted it as a solution answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because HappyTransformer does not support multi class probabilities I suggest to use another library. The library `flair` provides even more functionality and can give you your desired multi class probabilities, with something like this:

```
from flair.models import TextClassifier
from flair.data import Sentence

tc = TextClassifier.load('en-sentiment')

sentence = Sentence('Flair is pretty neat!')

tc.predict(sentence, multi_class_prob=True)

print('Sentence above is: ', sentence.labels)
```

Just `pip install flair` for usage.

Note that we use a different model than BERT and only returns two labels not three.

Another option is to use the `HuggingFace` library. It allows for using self defined labels.

```py
from transformers import pipeline

classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification")
classifier(
    "This is a course about the Transformers library",
    candidate_labels=["education", "politics", "business"],
)
```

```
{'sequence': 'This is a course about the Transformers library',
 'labels': ['education', 'business', 'politics'],
 'scores': [0.8445963859558105, 0.111976258456707, 0.043427448719739914]}
```

In your case, you switch out the labels to `["positive", "negative", "neutral"]`.

The examples are taken from: https://huggingface.co/course/chapter1/3?fw=pt

Comment: Hi - thank you very much for sharing that code. To confirm, ```flair``` supports multi class probabilities? And, is there a way to do this using my own dataset?

Comment: Yes you can train on your own datasets and supports multi calls probs

Comment: Cool - is there a guide or tutorial on how to do it?

Comment: You can look through here: https://github.com/flairNLP/flair/tree/d5dd0a2818418fb5afac2c01f1e9d1cf5767a51f It has a lot of informations.